# Determine x coordinate on a sine wave

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have this question which is puzzling me:

[image: sine wave]

I understand that to determine the x value from the equation `y = sin(x)` you would do `x = arcsin(y)` but how would i use this to determine the x value of b?

Thanks

Comment: Hint : $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Ok so point b is shifted 180 degrees along from a? So do I add sin(pi) ?

Comment: Not really. Note that the x-coordinate of A is the same distance away from 0 as the x-coordinate of B from $\pi$ (but in the other direction).

Comment: Subtract $x_A$ from $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to understand the "multivalued" aspect of $\sin^{-1}$ is to reverse the graphical representation of $y=\sin(x)$ and consider "layers" of two types (see figure below with a color code green/red):

$$\begin{cases}
y&=&\ \ \ \color{green}{\sin(x)}+2k \pi& \text{or}\\
y&=&\color{red}{-\sin(x)}+(2k+1) \pi
\end{cases} \ \ \ (\text{for integer values of } \ k )$$

with two "mother curves": one for $y=\sin^{-1}(x)$ (well recognizable) and the other one $y=-\sin(x)$ (dotted curve)

[image]